# Delete null rows in azure data factory data flow transformation

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a Data Flow transformation in Azure Data Factory

**Source** : Excel file uploaded in Azure Blob
**Destination** : JSON File created in Azure Blob

1. I do not want to insert null rows from source to target
2. If a particular row does not have a specific value then I want to insert value from earlier row.

I have tried to Filter transformation to filter out rows if all columns has null values using below expression , but it is not able to remove null rows

!(isNull(Column_1)) && !(isNull(Column_2)) && !(isNull(Column_3)) && !(isNull(Column_4)) && !(isNull(Column_5)) && !(isNull(Column_6))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the columns() function in your Filter to get the value from all columns per row. Put that inside an array() and then use contains() to search the array for the existence of values (i.e. not null). Notice you have to coalesce the array elements to string:

contains(array(toString(columns())),!isNull(#item))

Put that in your Filter expression, should work.

Comment: this worked. I think when we export data to JSON , it will anyway wont export NULL values , but I am exporting into azure sql as well , and I do not see any null rows there also

Comment: this worked great for me! how did you know to use `#item` syntax? is there documentation explaining that usage? I haven't seen it before, and it seems different than the `$$` or `@item` that I have seen

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-array-functions#array-function-list

Answer (score 0):

I used filter transform and provided below filter on condition

!(isNull(Prop_0))||!(isNull(Prop_1))||!(isNull(Prop_2))||!(isNull(Prop_3))||!(isNull(Prop_4))||!(isNull(Prop_5))||!(isNull(Prop_6))||!(isNull(Prop_7))||!(isNull(Prop_8))||!(isNull(Prop_9))||!(isNull(Prop_10))

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `equals()` to achieve what you want, like:

```
!equals(toString(Foo),'') && !equals(toString(Bar),'')
```